# Is it needed to filter/sanitize input if prepared statements are used?

Tags: php

Is it needed to filter/sanitize input if prepared statements are used or is it enough to sanitize/filter it on output? If the prepared statements are used the input cannot "hurt" only the output can which will be always sanitized and filtered.

Comment: You use prepared statements to stop [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) That is not the same as sanitizing your user input. You should still sanitize (remove or block nonsense and unintended values) from input BEFORE you store it onto a database. Why would you want rubbish on your database, remember it may not always be a 'system' that is retrieving it, it could be someone allowed to process it from say the command line, or some data wharehousing system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put EVERYTHING that comes from the user into a parameter, then, no, don't sanitize it. A parameter is automatically sanitized. If however you put something directly into an SQL string (concatenate strings), then, yes, you need to sanitize.